# How to let nginx ingress handle the request for a service on a k3s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want the nginx ingress load balancer to handle my request from other machines in my network/from the internet.

I have k3s with metallb, nginx-ingress and cert-manager installed. All pods are running. now I have the following deployment and service

```
# webserver-deployment.yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: httpd
  name: httpd
  namespace: webserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: httpd:2.4.46
        name: httpd
      nodeSelector:
        role: worker
status: {}


# webserver-service.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: httpd
  name: httpd
  namespace: webserver
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: httpd
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The service can be reached from the cluster

```
% curl 10.43.53.255
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Now when I use the ingress setting

```
# webserver-ingress.yaml
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: httpd-ingress
  namespace: webserver
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: httpd 
            port:
              number: 80
```

I thought that I can reach the the service from the ingress IP `192.168.178.240`

```
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.43.116.250   <none>            443/TCP                      3d     app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.43.10.136    192.168.178.240   80:31517/TCP,443:31733/TCP   3d     app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx-ingress,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
```

but when I call it I get

```
curl 192.168.178.240:80
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
% kubectl get ingress -n webserver httpd-ingress -oyaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx"},"name":"httpd-ingress","namespace":"webserver"},"spec":{"rules":[{"http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"httpd","servicePort":80},"path":"/"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-23T19:21:40Z"
  generation: 1
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
    manager: kubectl-client-side-apply
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-23T19:21:40Z"
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: nginx-ingress-controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-04-23T19:21:47Z"
  name: httpd-ingress
  namespace: webserver
  resourceVersion: "25412"
  uid: ab3706c5-8d93-4a91-b8ee-72bc7995f662
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: httpd
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.178.36
```

```
$ curl 192.168.178.36
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.178.36 port 80: Connection refused
```

which is unequal to from above? so how do I set up the ingress correctly?

Comment: can you add a describe of the Ingress?

Comment: Do you mean of the pod nginx ingress controller?

Comment: No I was talking about the Ingress resource. `k get ingress -n webserver httpd-ingress -oyaml`

Comment: But the file you posted, webserver-ingress.yaml, defines an ingress in that namespace. That's the definition that associates the service with a path when requesting to the Nginx Ingress Controller

Comment: Ok I added it, I was on the wrong machine

Comment: Ok, as you can see under `status.loadBalancer`, the Ingress is not being served by the Nginx Ingress Controller (there should be a section with a list that contains at least an ip address, which is the address of the controller that is serving the ingress in question), that is why you can't reach your service at the external ip of the Nginx Pod. I would check the IngressClasses of your cluster to see if there's a default one, something like `k get IngressClass` and then a `k get IngressClass <name-of-the-ingress-class> -oyaml`

Comment: Thank you. I could not find the command to list the ingress classes. I will keep trying

Comment: Does it work when you curl from the same cluster/pc? I assume you've configured [layer 2](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration) of MetalLB and it's gonna work only on your pc. I've verified the ingress and your deployment and it's correct.

Comment: yes I configured metalLB `$ helm install metallb stable/metallb --namespace kube-system \
    --set configInline.address-pools[0].name=default \
    --set configInline.address-pools[0].protocol=layer2 \
    --set configInline.address-pools[0].addresses[0]=192.168.178.240-192.168.178.250`  When I curl from the master I still get that from above